# Sketch - move an existing symbol to the "symbols" page without breaking the connection with its instances

Tags: sketch-app

I have a symbol which I created and placed instances of on various artboards on Pages A and B. I created it without checking the "send to symbols page" option, so the symbol definition lives on Page A. I want to now move it to the "symbols" page. How do I do this without breaking its connection with all its instances and having to select all the instances and click "replace with symbol"?

I tried to cut the symbol definition, but I got this warning:
[image: Warning message: if you cut a symbol from this document, its instances will convert into groups.]

- Sketch Version 41 (35326)
- Mac OS 10.11.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in case anybody is looking for this now... they have added "send to symbols page" as an option in the right click menu. Can also be done to symbols one a time by dragging them.  Note that dragging multiple symbols breaks overrides in Sketch 56.3 (and likely other versions).

[image: Just right click on the symbol, choose "send to symbols page" :)]

Answer (score 7):

You can drag the symbol to the symbols page in the layers/pages panel.

[image: Sketch symbol drag to symbols page]

I am not aware of way to do this via keyboard shortcuts or menus. I think it has to be done via dragging.